# Command to tell WHEN you ran the last executed command in bash?

Tags: bash, terminal

Is there a command or a technique to figure out exactly what time I ran the last command in bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the bash history:

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T "
```

this will log the commands you enter on the terminal (not the ones that are run inside a script).

view the result with the command `history` or inspect `~/.bash_history`.

To make this permanent, add the above line to `~/.bashrc`.